# What could be causing this socket not to find a port?

Tags: java, sockets, udp, datagram

I am trying to create a server that receives UDP packets and responds with UDP messages.  However, I can't seem to get it to bind to a port.  Here's my constructor for the class:

```
public UDPServer() throws IOException {
    myGUI = new ServerGUI();
    myClientList = new ArrayList<ClientInfo>();
    DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open();
    mySocket = channel.socket();

    //mySocket = new DatagramSocket(null);      
    //mySocket.setReuseAddress(true);
    //mySocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", Constants.SERVER_PORT_NUM));

    myPortNum = mySocket.getPort();
    myIP = mySocket.getInetAddress();
    System.out.println(myPortNum + "   " + myIP.toString());
}
```

I have tried both the channel method and the commented out method, and I even used this method to try and find an open port:

```
private DatagramSocket createNewSocket() throws IOException {
    for (int i = Constants.MIN_PORT_NUM; i < Constants.MAX_PORT_NUM; i++){
        try {
            System.out.println(i);
            return new DatagramSocket(i);
        } catch (IOException e){
            continue; // try next port
        }
    }

    throw new IOException("No free port found");
}
```

But I've had no luck so far.  The portNum keeps coming up as `-1` and the IP is `null`.  Any ideas what could be going on here?

EDIT: When I run the following in debug mode and scroll over mySocket to see what values it contains, it says that:

```
bound = true
closed = false
connectedAddress = null
connectedPort = -1
```

But when I run `mySocket.getLocalPort()`, it returns a valid port number.  What's going on here?

Here's the code:

```
public UDPServer() throws IOException {
    myGUI = new ServerGUI();
    myClientList = new ArrayList<ClientInfo>();

    mySocket = new DatagramSocket(Constants.SERVER_PORT_NUM);
    mySocket.setReuseAddress(true);

    myPortNum = mySocket.getLocalPort();
    myIP = mySocket.getInetAddress();
    System.out.println(mySocket);
}
```

Comment: This is a pretty good and simple tutorial for using sockets that you can use as reference. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/clientServer.html

In any case I think you need to specify a port for your server.

Comment: Setting `reuseAddress(true)` *after* you've bound to a port, which is what `new DatagramSocket(int port)` does (including when `port` is zero), is entirely futile. It's too late to do any good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do this. Just create it with the non-args constructor, or specify port zero. The system will allocate a free port for you.

Comment: Would you mind showing me what you mean by that?  I have already tried `mySocket = new DatagramSocket(0)` if that's what you're saying.

Comment: And the problem with that was what exactly? You will almost certainly succeed in creating the socket, and then all you have to to is call `getLocalPort()` to find out what the allocated port was.

Comment: Just made an edit with what I'm getting now.  What might be happening?

Comment: What might be happening with what? What's your question now?